# Error using the connection to database when RDS scales out

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, amazon-ecs, connection-pooling, aws-aurora-serverless

We have a .net API hosted in ECS that queries data from a serverless v1 cluster using Entity Framework. Under normal load this service performs very well but when there's a large spike in traffic that require the RDS cluster to scale out to more ACUs we are seeing a lot of connection errors in our API.

`An error occurred using the connection to database '\"ourdatabasename\"' on server '\"tcp://ourcluster.region.rds.amazonaws.com:5432\"'.`

The high level overiew of the infrastructure looks like this:

`CloudFront >> Load Balancer >> ECS Fargate >> RDS Aurora PostgeSQL Serverless v1`

Stack information:

- .Net 6 API compiled for Linux
- Entity Framework Core 6.x
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.x
- PostgeSQL 10.18

We did open AWS support cases about this issue in the past year, but those basically always result in the answer that this is an implementation issue and not an infrastructure issue.

We can easily reproduce the issue by running a k6 stress test on our API (bypassing the CloudFront caching layer of course) to generate a spike high enough to trigger scaling of the RDS cluster.

For the past year we have worked around this issue by configuring RDS at a capacity at which it basically never needs to scale out. This is of course wasting money, and not the purpose of serverless as all, so we would like to find the underlying root cause and solve that.

Some things we have tried already:

- We have experimented with **serverless v2** which should scale in a completely different fashion as it's just the same vm consuming more resources from the hosting machine. But our preliminary conclusion is that this was even worse. We do not yet understand why that is, but it appears to trigger the same effect but than a lot faster/more as v2 scales a lot faster/more. With v1 we get in trouble around 400 requests per second, with v2 it was at 150rps.
- `EnableRetryOnFailure` seemed to help a tiny bit, but not a lot. We have left it at the default configuration as implemented by Npgsql for now.
- We have experimented with the `Maximum Pool Size` connection string parameter. At 300 it appears to be a bit better, but it does not solve the issue.
- Changing the scaling behaviour of ECS/the ALB or even just prescaling that to handle peak load did not change anything.

We have not tried:

- RDS Proxy, it's supposed to solve all your connection pooling issues. But we're not sure it's even a pooling issue. We're not keen on trusting on yet another black box service to solve the issues our first black box service (aurora serverless) has. And it's not really cheap. If all of SO will now convince us this is the holy grail, then surely we'll try it out.
- Data API for RDS, you can't have connection management issues if you're not making them right? It's a huge investment to rewrite all EF code to Data API requests and I'm not sure what it says about the service if it's still not out for serverless v2. So, not for now I think.

The first purpose of this question here on SO it trying to find someone that could help us understand what is even going on. Helping us understand the error and where it comes from. We understand that you cannot expect that ECS+RDS can just magically handle all the load you throw at it. But if we do not fully understand how it breaks we are not able to come up with how to create potential failover mechanisms or how to make the system fail more gracefully.

If someone knows the magic setting but not the why that's also great of course :) We can then maybe figure out the why ourselves and share that back with the community ;)

Feel free to ask more questions where needed.

Comment: We are seeing the same issue at load using a similar stack except with MySql, but we don't have auto-scaling and are using M5.xLarge.  Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: No, we learned to live with it for now. We use various configurations of aurora serverless/provisioned postgres/mysql and all of them have connection issues during scaling. So we do things like prescaling before peak hours and making sure that any callers will implement retry mechanisms.

Comment: Finally found someone who has same issue. No idea where it comes from too. Most times could reproduce, but not guranteed. Using almost same just .net 7.